# Was bedeutet "abkündigen"?

Tags: meaning

Ich meine hier die konkrete Bedeutung im Zusammenhang mit Softwareprodukten und Systemvoraussetzungen. Zum Beispiel:

> Wird es vielleicht Zeit die Unterstützung von SQL-Server-2000 abzukündigen?

Aber meines Wissens wird der Begriff auch in anderen Bereichen gebraucht.

Comment: Begriff ist mir neu, obwohl ich in der Branche arbeite.

Comment: Wird vielleicht Zeit die Unterstützung von SQL-Server 2000 abzukündigen?

Comment: @splattne: Ich stimme dir zu. Ich arbeite seit 20 Jahren in der Softwarebranche und habe dieses Wort noch nie gehört. Ich kenne "kündigen" und "aufkündigen", zwei Synonyne mit der Bedeutung "einen Vertag (vorzeitig) beenden", aber "abkündigen" ist mir neu und ich weiß auch nicht was es bedeuten soll und wie es gebraucht werden könnte.

Comment: @bernd_k: Also das Ende der Unterstützung ankündigen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Abkündigen" ist meiner Meinung nach oft eine Beschönigung von "absagen" oder "beenden". Ein Produkt (aus welcher Branche auch immer), welches nicht mehr betrieben oder unterstützt wird, wird [abgekündigt](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/abk%C3%BCndigen). Im Prinzip ist es also die Ankündigung der Beendigung. Es ist natürlich wie immer Geschmackssache, was besser klingt, aber ich kann schon nachvollziehen, wenn

> Das Produkt wird eingestellt.

zugunsten von

> Hiermit kündigen wir das Produkt ab.

fallen gelassen wird.

Interessanterweise ist die ursprüngliche Bedeutung eine [kirchliche](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/abkuendigen).

Einen Zusammenhang zu "Systemvoraussetzungen" kann ich nicht herstellen.

Comment: Das mit den Systemvoraussetzungen tritt zum Beispiel ein, wenn man bestimmte Betriebssysteme z.B. Windows XP nicht mehr als Basis für ein bestimmtes Programm unterstützen will. Es ergeht dann die klare Ansage, das künftige Versionen des Programms ein geändertes Betriebssystem erfordern. Der Benutzer kann sich dann darauf einstellen. Er bleibt bei der aktuellen Version des Programms, er beschafft sich ein neues Betriebssystem oder er sucht einen alternatives Programm, welches auf dem alten Betriebssystem läuft.

Comment: Die neuere Bedeutung unterscheidet sich m.E. schon leicht von _einstellen_. Ich kenne es eher aus dem Bereich elektronischer Bauelemente, deren Produktion auch dann, wenn sie _abgekündigt_ wurden, noch nicht _eingestellt_ ist. Die Abkündigung ist lediglich ein Hinweis, diese Bauteile nicht mehr für neue Produkte (also neue Typen) zu verwenden; der Verwendung in der Herstellung neuer Exemplare bereits geplanter Produkte steht sie aber nicht entgegen.

Comment: Die gematik (Entwickler für die Spezifikationen der elektronischen Gesundheitskarte) benutzt das Wort für obsolete Spezifikationen (http://www.gematik.de/cms/de/spezifikation/abgekuendigte_releases/release_4_0_0/release_4_0_0.jsp)

Answer (score 8):

Interessant finde ich, dass nur einer die kirchliche Ursprungsbedeutung erwähnt hat.

Bereits im Mittelalter wurden wichtige Nachrichten, die die Bewohner einer Stadt erreichen mussten, öffentlich bekanntgemacht oder verkündet, indem die Nachrichten mündlich (z. B. von einem Boten) vorgetragen wurden, da es in dieser Zeit nicht üblich war, dass alle Lesen und Schreiben konnten.

Entsprechend wurden wichtige Nachrichten, die das Gemeindewesen, das Zusammenleben in der kirchlichen Gemeinde betrafen, im Gottesdienst (den damals praktisch jeder besucht hat) vom Pfarrer öffentlich bekannt gemacht. Dementsprechend enthielten diese Abkündigungen Informationen darüber, welche Gemeindemitglieder gestorben waren, welche geheiratet oder das Aufgebot bestellt hatten, welche Kinder geboren wurden, wie hoch die Kollekte des letzten Gottesdienstes war, wofür die heutige Kollekte verwendet werden soll, wann der nächste Gottesdienst stattfindet, usw.

Diese Bekanntmachungen können im Rahmen der Liturgie zu verschiedenen Zeitpunkten gemacht werden, werden aber meistens zum Ende des Gottesdienstes "abgekündigt".

Die ursprüngliche Bedeutung der "Abkündigung" ist also die Verkündigung von wichtigen Nachrichten, das "ab" kann von "Ablesen" oder von "am Ende der Veranstaltung" (vergleichbar der Anrede (Lieber xy) und der Abrede (Mit freundlichen Grüßen) in Briefen) abgeleitet werden.

Zum Hintergrund siehe [in dieser deutschen Enzyklopädie](http://www.enzyklo.de/Begriff/Abk%C3%BCndigung) und diese Informationen zum Thema [Abkündigungen im Gottesdienst](http://www.der-evangelische-gottesdienst.de/abkuendigung-informationen-hinweise.htm) nach.

Answer (score 6):

"Abkündigen" wird, wie schon der Aufbau des Worts andeutet, als Gegenteil von "ankündigen" verwendet.

Ich kenne es in dieser Verwendung besonders aus dem IT-Geschäft: Wird ein Produkt abgekündigt, kündigt der Hersteller damit an, dass die Produktion eingestellt werden wird. Abgekündigte Produkte können noch, als Lagerbestände, eine Zeit lang im Handel auftauchen, sie werden aber in absehbarer Zeit vom Hersteller nicht mehr gepflegt werden.