# What is the English translation of "abkündigen"?

Tags: german-to-english

The meaning of the German word "abkündigen" is discussed [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2850/was-bedeutet-abkundigen). I'm interested in translating sentenses like:

> Das Betriebssystem Windows XP wird von Narhalla 2.0  (Release
>   11.11.2011) nicht mehr unterstützt.

From [this](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136/are-translation-requests-from-german-allowed-sind-fragen-nach-bersetzungen) discussion on meta, I can't derive if this question is off topic here.

Comment: Why do translation-requests to English appear in the german.SO, rather than the english.SO?

Comment: @feela Please look http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/136/are-translation-requests-from-german-allowed-sind-fragen-nach-bersetzungen. Perhaps in the end they will go to http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/16613/languages, where it is intended to be on topic. Currently this is the only page, where I can hope to get an answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about English, not German.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A typical verb is

> to discontinue

e.g. support for a product.

So, something along the lines of

> We will discontinue supporting Win XP for Narhalla 2.0 and later versions.

Answer (score -1):

There is no commonly used word *abkündigen* in German — maybe in specialized use (e.g. contract)?
I think it is a simple mistyping of *a**n**kündigen*, meaning *to announce*, as *B* and *N* are neighbours on the keyboard.

Comment: In colloquial use you may be right, but at least in a business context it is relatively common.

Comment: Welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. For any questions about how it works, consult the [help].

Comment: [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/abkündigen) defines it as "die Absetzung eines Produktes vom Markt ankündigen".